# Working Google Maps v3 now show empty canvas

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api

So these Google Maps were working fine and then all of a sudden they weren't. The only change I made was uploading new images for the markers. Upon inspection I can see that the new markers are loading properly and the console produces no errors (Chrome and FF). I have tried flipping the sensor between true and false, also with no luck. When I removed the sensor attrib it kicked back the standard alert error of needing it.

Am I missing something simple?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYAPIKEY&sensor=false">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var wildbasin = new google.maps.LatLng(30.310716, -97.824238);
  var seucampus =  new google.maps.LatLng(30.229723, -97.755275);
  var austin =  new google.maps.LatLng(30.275079, -97.792053);
  var basinm = 'http://www.test.stedwards.edu/sites/default/files/wildbasinmarker_1.png';
  var campusm = 'http://www.test.stedwards.edu/sites/default/files/maincampusmarker_0.png';
  var map;
  function initialize() {
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 12,
      center: austin,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), myOptions);

  var  campus = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: seucampus, 
    map: map,
    title:"St.Edward's University",
    icon: campusm

});   

  var  thebasin = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: wildbasin, 
    map: map,
    title:"Wild Basin",
    icon:basinm

});   

}
     google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>

<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: Do you have a link to a map that exhibits the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the map will default to 100% width, you need to set a height for the containing div.  For example, this will solve your issue:

```
<div id="map_canvas" style="height:400px;"></div>
```

Comment: You nailed it. A style tag elsewhere must have been changed.